# Data binding between controller and service in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-services, angular-factory

I want to know the correct way to do the following, I have a service, a factory, and a controller.

The service has a `selectedTable` property that starts as `null` by default and it's used to store the selected table in order to be used in both the factory and the controller; the service also has a `touches` property that it's updated regularly in the factory and the controller, that service looks like this:

```
Module.service('tablesService', function(){
    this.data = {
        selectedTable: null,
        touches: 0
    }
});
```

The factory uses the service by setting up a variable `var data = tablesService.data` and has a method `select` that modifies the value of `data.selectedTable` and `data.touches`:

```
if (data.selectedTable === this){
    data.touches++;
    if (data.touches === 2) {
        data.selectedTable = null;
    }       
} else {
    if (data.selectedTable && data.selectedTable != this) {
        data.touches++;
        data.selectedTable.select();
    }
    data.selectedTable = this;
}
```

The controller looks in a list of tables on every `onClick` event  and when it founds the clicked table calls it's `select()` method, the one in the factory, if the table clicked is the selectedTable, it changes the `touches` variable so when it's `select()` method it's called, the `selectedTable` get's `null` as the new value.

```
$scope.tablesData = tablesService.data;
$scope.selectedTable = $scope.tablesData.selectedTable;
$scope.touches = $scope.tablesData.touches;

$scope.findTable = function(event){
    $scope.touches = 0;
    for(t in $scope.tables) {
        var table = $scope.tables[t];
        var result = table.findMe(event.offsetX,event.offsetY);
        if(result.type === 'table') {
            if ($scope.selectedTable === table){
                $scope.touches++;
            }
        table.select();
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that changing `$scope.touches` won't update the variable in the service and vice-versa, this also happens with the selectedTable, I tried using `$watch` on both `$scope.touches` and `$scope.tablesData.touches` but the `$digest()` method doesn't fire up every time I change `$scope.touches` so I have to call `$apply()` which looks awful and doesn't solve the problem all the time.

My watchers look like this:

```
$scope.$watch('touches', function(){
    $scope.tablesData.touches = $scope.touches;
});
$scope.$watch('tablesData.touches', function(){
    $scope.touches = $scope.tablesData.touches;
});
```

Reading this post http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/ I found out that I can broadcast an event to the application via $rootScope.$broadcast(), but I'm not really sure how to implement that and perhaps that's not the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: This is happening because you are assigning `$scope.touches` to the *primitive property* `touches` on the service object.  Primitives are copied **byVal** rather than **byRef**.  Why do you even need `$scope.touches` anyway?  `$scope.tablesData.touches` is the reference to the correct property on the correct object, which is **byRef**, and already accessible in all the code that `$scope.touches` would be.

Comment: @Claies yeah, I know that primitives are passed by value and not reference, I want to know if there's a better way to do this rather than using watchers, at first I used `$scope.tablesData.touches` but with the time the controller's been getting bigger and bigger so I created a bunch of factories and services and the controller looks really messy having a lot of `$scope.somethingData.someProp`

Comment: I would rather use `scope.someProp`, even if I have to setup a method at the start of the controller that updates the value in the service and the controller everytime it changes in any of them.

Comment: not only is that a lot of extra work, it is also misleading.  by referencing `serivce.property` it is very clear in the code and in the markup that this property belongs to the specific service.  by cloning the property and then trying to keep the clone up to date manually, you are introducing a new potential failure point, as well as making your markup less clear.

Comment: alright, I'm getting used to the idea, however, if I have something like $scope.zonesData.activeZone.plans.tables = <an array> should I use that hell of an expression or is it better something like $scope.tables = <same array> ??

Comment: Well, I would probably start with getting rid of `$scope`, in favor of the `controllerAs` syntax.  from there, I would break the views down into components, and provide supporting services for those components.  in this way, you can be modular, but not tied to a `$scope` tree hierarchy where you are climbing multiple branches to get to your leaves.  start here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y030

Comment: @Claies thanks for the help, that guide looks awesome, I'll check it out.